Is there a port of the Windows' REN command for Unix-like operating systems?
I already know the rename command in GNU/Linux. However, it is very complicated and cumbersome because it uses regular expressions.
For example, in Windows, I can simply rename files in bulk by typing:
REN *.txt *.sh

But with the rename command in GNU/Linux, I have to use:
rename 's/\\.txt$/.sh/' *.txt

This is very cumbersome. While it may become slightly easier if I fully memorize regular expressions, it is still tedious due to the large number of characters I have to type.
Is there a port of the Windows' REN command for Unix-like operating systems? Or, are there any programs that perform equivalent functions to the REN command?

There cannot be an equivalent of ren *.txt *.sh because,  in Linux, the wildcards (*.txt and *.sh) are expanded by the parent process (the shell), and the ren command sees only the expanded wildcards.

Probably the closest are the rename command from the util-linux package - which to avoid conflict with the Perl-based file-rename is sometimes installed as rename.ul - or the mmv command. For example given
$ ls *.txt
bar.txt  baz.txt  foo.txt

then
$ rename.ul -nv .txt .sh *.txt
`bar.txt' -> `bar.sh'
`baz.txt' -> `baz.sh'
`foo.txt' -> `foo.sh'

or
$ mmv -n '*.txt' '#1.sh'
bar.txt -> bar.sh
baz.txt -> baz.sh
foo.txt -> foo.sh

In zsh, there's the contributed zmv module that operates somewhat like mmv (but can make use of the z shell's more powerful glob library):
 % autoload -Uz zmv

 % zmv -n -w '*.txt' '$1.sh'
mv -- bar.txt bar.sh
mv -- baz.txt baz.sh
mv -- foo.txt foo.sh

(In all cases -n is a "no-op" flag - remove it to allow actual renaming.)
